# Drupal6: inline style being added to content only in IE7; not by me?

Tags: theming

I know this will sound open, but has anyone ever experienced a Menu in Drupal being assigned an inline style of display:none within IE7?

I have triple checked all my own style-sheets, all settings and fields I can think of within Drupal and the menu creation screens and my page.tpl.php file.

Somehow, only in IE7 is that inline style applied and I've no idea if this is a Drupal thing or not. I've never seen this happen.

The menu disappearing is a custom pane piece of content and it's used on another page and shows up fine so my first thought was that the pages content had a clearing issue but then in the debugging tools, I find the display:none.

It's too much to post everything, obviously but I thought maybe some ideas of what could be going on would help lead me to other areas to investigate.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if you visit the page with javascript turned off? Or in another browser with no extensions enabled?

Comment: Yes. I thought perhaps one of the myriad of javascripts this site is using could be the culprit. But, I just literally found something. In the body content of that page was a simple ul no styles at all. By commenting it out, the problem disappeared so I just restyled the links as links instead of a UL and all is good. Still a weird one!

Comment: well, I spoke too soon. Another menu is now getting the same issue but the content isn't affecting this one. I've disabled all js and still it gets a display:none. This is only in IE7; no other browser on Mac/Win exhibit this. Strange